# Boost function + boost bind complicated situation

Tags: c++, function, boost, bind

I have member function:

```
void ClassA::Method(ClassB& inputarg);
```

and I want to have boost::function :

```
boost::function< void (ClassB&) > 
            FunctionPointer(
            boost::bind((&ClassA::Method, _1, _2)(ClassC->ClassA_User, boost::ref(SomeStructure.ClassB_User)));
```

but it doesn't compile, what i do wrong ?

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
>    error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t<_bi::dm_result::type,boost::_mfi::dm,_bi::list_av_1::type> boost::bind(M T::* ,A1)' : expects 2 arguments - 1 provided
>   7>          c:\git\3rdparty\common\include\boost\bind\bind.hpp(1728) : see declaration of 'boost::bind'
>   error C2780: 'boost::_bi::bind_t,_bi::list_av_9::type> boost::bind(boost::type,R (__thiscall T::* )(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8) const,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)' : expects 11 arguments - 1 provided
>   7>          c:\git\3rdparty\common\include\boost\bind\bind_mf2_cc.hpp(223) : see declaration of 'boost::bind'

and many more similar to last line of output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want create `boost::function<void(B&)>`, then use just

```
FunctionPointer(boost::bind(&ClassA::Method, ClassC->ClassA_User, _1));
```

call it like `FunctionPointer(SomeStructure.ClassB_User);`

If you want to pass in bind known instance of `B`, then type of `FunctionPointer` should be

```
boost::function<void()>
```

and bind should be like this

```
boost::bind(&ClassA::Method, ClassC->ClassA_User,
boost::ref(SomeStructure.ClassB_User)));
```

then call it like
`FunctionPointer()`;

Comment: If a `boost::function<void(ClassB&)>` is desired (as opposed to `boost::function<void()>`), then there does indeed need to be a placeholder.

Comment: I have one more question, because right now i bind copy of object ClassA_User, how can I bind reference ?

    boost::bind(&ClassA::Method, &ClassC->ClassA_User,
boost::ref(SomeStructure.ClassB_User)));

is incorrect.

Comment: Use `boost::ref` on `ClassA_User`